# CSS transition stacking?

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS to slide menu's. With JS I only add a class to trigger CSS animations. In desktop mode, the menu is exists out of 4 columns with list items. In mobile mode, the menu will collapse and only the headings remain. The headings are clickable to open the menu.

My menu is running fine, but the animation of sliding down is different from sliding up. Sliding up is also slower / starting later. I don't understand why this is happening, I want the same effect for sliding down and sliding up.

See my JSfiddle: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o36x6x2q/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-footer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25p">
            <span class="footer-heading">Heading 1</span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25p">
            <span class="footer-heading">Heading 2</span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25p">
            <span class="footer-heading">Heading 3</span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-25p">
            <span class="footer-heading">Heading 4</span>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.site-footer {
font-size: 1.3rem;

.footer-heading {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 4px;

    &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;

        @media (min-width: 768px){
            cursor: default;
        }
    }

    &::after {
        font-family: "FontAwesome";
        float: right;
        content: "\f078";
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;

        @media (min-width: 768px){
            content: "";
        }
    }

    &.open{
        &::after{
            transform: rotate(180deg);
        }

        & + div{
            max-height:500px;
            //transition:all 500ms ease;
            transition-property: all;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
        }
    }


    & + div {
        overflow-y: hidden;
        max-height: 0;
        transition-property: all;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);

        @media (min-width: 768px){
            max-height: 500px;
        }
    }

}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;

    li {
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;

        a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;

            &:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;

            }
        }
    }
}
}


.col-25p{
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.site-footer .footer-heading').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're animating the `max-height` property. It animates from `0px` to `500px` and back. However the divs to animate are smaller than `500px`.

That's why the delay is there on the closing animation.

The way I normally solve this is by setting the `max-height` property on the elements by using JavaScript.

Comment: You mean to determine the height with JS and add a `style:max-height:` to it with JS?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean!

Answer (score -1):

Please set in `& + div`

```
transition:all 500ms ease;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
```

**Please try this**

```
.site-footer {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

    .footer-heading {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-top: 4px;

        &:hover{
            cursor: pointer;

            @media (min-width: 768px){
                cursor: default;
            }
        }

        &::after {
            font-family: "FontAwesome";
            float: right;
            content: "\f078";
            transition:all 500ms ease;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);

            @media (min-width: 768px){
                content: "";
            }
        }

        &.open{
            &::after{
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }

            & + div{
               max-height:500px;
               transition:all 500ms ease;
               transition-property: all;
               transition-duration: 1s;
               transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
            }
        }


        & + div {
            overflow-y: hidden;
            max-height: 0;
            transition-property: all 500ms ease;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);

            @media (min-width: 768px){
                max-height: 500px;
            }
        }

    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;

        li {
            padding-top: 4px;
            padding-bottom: 4px;

            a {
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;

                &:hover {
                    text-decoration: underline;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


.col-25p{
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    float:left;
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```